# GDI+ image scaling issue

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, gdi+, scaling

I have an application which draws background from some bitmap using gdi+. Some of bitmaps are vertical non-linear gradients (e.g. they are 1 pixel wide and should be stretched horizontally to fill whole control width). 
The problem is that with small images (like described above), some control area on the right is not painted.

I've written a test program that scales a 1x1 image to different sizes, and it shows that issue occurs when scale factor is big enough

```
void Draw(HDC hDestDC, int destleft, int desttop, int destwidth, int destheight)
{
    COLORREF buffer[] = {0xFF0000FF }; // 1 pixel image
    const int width = 1, height = 1;
    Gdiplus::Bitmap gdipBitmap(width, height, 4*width, PixelFormat32bppARGB, (BYTE*)buffer);

    Gdiplus::ImageAttributes attrs;
    Gdiplus::Rect dest(destleft, desttop, destwidth, destheight);

    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hDestDC);
    graphics.SetInterpolationMode(Gdiplus::InterpolationModeNearestNeighbor);
    graphics.SetPixelOffsetMode(Gdiplus::PixelOffsetModeHalf);

    graphics.DrawImage(&gdipBitmap, dest, 0, 0, width, height, Gdiplus::UnitPixel, &attrs);
}

// OnPaint:
for(int i=0; i<800; ++i)
    Draw(hdc, 0, i, i, 1); // scale 1x1 image to different width
```

I would exptect this test to draw a smooth 'triangle', but instead lines do not have size *exactly* as specified by destination rect: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9rev.png

Is there any way to fix this behavior? I need to output bitmap with size exactly as specified (considering source image alpha-channel and no interpolation with background on the edges).

P.S: I have to use GDI+ because actual code uses some ImageAttributes provided by gdiplus.

Comment: I see the same issue, when target image size is around 1% from original size, GDI+ scaling method creates corrupted image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I just ended up trying all possible values for different options and finally found ones suitable for me.

`SetSmoothingMode` (as suggested by Na Na) didn't have any visual effect on the image.

However `SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeBilinear)` (or better) produces exact image size, but it also interpolates image edges with background. The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Eua.png), which doesn't suit my requirements.

Finally, setting `ImageAttibute`'s `WrapMode` option does the trick:

```
attrs.SetWrapMode(Gdiplus::WrapModeTileFlipXY);
```

The result is exactly what I wanted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umfw3.png

### Summary:

Using `InterpolationModeNearestNeighbor` **and** default `WrapMode` results in inaccurate rendered image size. To avoid this, set `WrapModeTileFlipXY` => Other options (like `InterpolationMode`) can have any desirable value without influence on the rendered image size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Anti-aliasing smoothing method might help.

Comment: That's for lines, curves and fills, not bitmaps.